# Is there a threat in router backdoors if I only use SSL?

Tags: tls, man-in-the-middle, router

If there is a backdoor in a modem or router, it can execute a MITM attack. But what if I use SSL (actually TLS)? We use TLS in order to prevent MITM attacks anywhere on the way (such as the ISP, the website's host, or anyone else). Is the router any worse than any other step between the client and a website?

Answer (score 4):

Regarding TLS, your home router should be the same as any other node, eg. from your ISP.

In company settings, it is somewhat common that each company computer also has a CA certificate from the router, and the router checks all traffic - in this case of course HTTPS is broken by design, and someone able to access the router can access all traffic data too.

And not directly related to TLS, but: Always remember that attacking HTTPS is not the only thing. A home router has a direct connection to your computer and can send/receive *everything* there. Network stack exploits, Intel AMT, DHCP weaknesses, something to take over your network printer and send all print jobs to the attacker, etc.etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Let's assume a simple consumer case with no CA certificate from the router. And let's restrict it further to the computer itself, as opposed to other network devices such as printers.  And furthermore, let's assume that the (only) computer has the network set as _public_ to prevent the router from accessing its files. Can you elaborate on the other exploits?

Comment: Well, everything on your computer that touches network traffic at some point (be it a part of your OS, mainboard, browser, or whatever) can have bugs that, with specific data received, can lead to unwanted things - for some bugs an attacker can use this to get in. There are far too many such bugs to list them here. Keeping your software updated and relying on the developers to fix such bugs is the usual solution there (and as you said, properly configuring things to not allow bad things).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So _in theory_ a router shouldn't be able to get information from the computer, or send information there (because of TLS), but in practice...

Answer (score 3):

There are still a lot of attacks possible with a MitM position on a network.

- **Network Surveillance**: a MitM can tell what domains you're connecting to, even with TLS, and can tell how much traffic you exchange each way and with what timings, which may be usable to determine things about how you use those sites or services. It may also be usable to fingerprint your OS / browser, based on things like supported TLS cipher suites and the size of HTTPS requests (which are often of predictable length, except for the user-agent string).
  If the attacker has other sources of knowledge, such as an ad network or similar online tracking, the attacker may be able to tease out who you are and what you do by correlating your IP address and network traffic with the tracking data.
  The attacker could also simply record all TLS traffic, especially traffic that doesn't have perfect forward secrecy, and store it against the possibility of being able to obtain the servers' private keys (or otherwise crack the key exchange) in the future, and therefore decrypt the sessions.
- **Device Surveillance**: The attacker knows everything that the router knows. This includes things like your OS host names ("Computer name"), WiFi network name, WiFi password (hope you didn't re-use it anywhere), and so on. The router can also scan for other nearby WiFi networks, which can be used to identify your physical location in most cases.
  An attacker could also identify the models of your devices, unless you take extra care to spoof their MAC addresses. The attacker would be able to know when new devices appear (such as due to guests or newly-purchased hardware), and when devices (such as your cell phone) go out of range, which could indicate what times you leave and enter the house.
- **Protocol Attacks**: Most attacks against SSL/TLS - and there have been a number, and will surely be more in the future - have required or at least been easier to carry out from a MitM position. This includes both attacks on the standard cryptographic operations and protocol-specified behavior, and attacks on the actual libraries used (such as OpenSSL).
- **Denial Of Service**: An attacker in such a MitM position can prevent you from connecting to certain servers, or cause connection issues (dropped packets, reset TCP connections, etc.), or just outright take your connection offline at will. This could also be selectively applied to specific devices.
- **Standard MITM Attacks**: TLS isn't a perfect panacea against MitM. The attacker could try to trick you (or somebody less savvy than you) into clicking through a certificate error screen, of course. The attacker could also look for apps that have weak TLS server verification (some apps don't verify server certificates at all; others simply don't do it correctly) or machines that trust bad CA certificates (see [Lenovo's fiasco with Superfish](https://www.digicert.com/blog/lenovos-superfish-adware-perils-self-signed-certificates/)) and compromise them. Finally, if an attacker manages to compromise a CA or obtain a fraudulent certificate with a trusted signature, the attacker could generate / use the fraudulent certificate(s) to MitM your connections.
- **Misuse Of Resources**: Modern home routers are, effectively, low-power computers. Anything a computer can do, such as participate in DDoS attacks or mine cryptocurrencies, the attacker could make your router do. Botnets of compromised embedded devices ("Internet of Things", in practice, includes routers) have been used for many attacks recently.

  **Legal Jeopardy**: Continuing the last point, the attacker could do things like launch "cyberattacks" and have them look like you did it. The attacker could also do things like download child pornography and store it in your router, not caring whether you get caught (or even specifically aiming to get you caught, if the attacker has it in for you in particular or just wants to ruin somebody's day) and potentially ruining your life.

Don't let random people you don't trust use your computers (and a router counts) and Internet connection. That's just a bad idea, even if you *somehow* manage to ensure that nothing ever goes over plain text.